# Listdata.svc Environmental error

Tags: rest, listdata.svc

I have a query that works in UAT but when I run the same thing in Production, I get a 500 Internal error. The field that's breaking is 'ITProjectManager' which is of type 'Person or Group'. When I remove this field it works but nothing has changed in the Project list they contain the same fields and data.

```
https://<siteURL>/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Project?$select=ProjectName,ProjectCode,Region,Division,InServiceDate,AFE,ITStatusValue,ITProjectManager/Name,SiteUrl&$orderby=ProjectName asc&$filter=(HiddenValue eq 'No') and ((ITStatusValue ne 'Closed') )&$expand=ITProjectManager,Region,Division
```

EDIT:
I just tested this in Chrome and it works. But it doesn't in IE

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was due to a bad record that came over from migration. A required 'Person or Group' field was left null possibly because a user didn't exist between the move from UAT to PROD. To discover this, I used the $top clause to determine which record was the culprit

```
https://<siteURL>/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Project?$select=ProjectName,ProjectCode,Region,Division,InServiceDate,AFE,ITStatusValue,ITProjectManager/Name,SiteUrl&$orderby=ProjectName asc&$filter=(HiddenValue eq 'No') and ((ITStatusValue ne 'Closed') )&$expand=ITProjectManager,Region,Division&$top=70
```

I could load $top=69 records but the 70th would break the query. That identified where the issue was